# How to check if all values in the list are the same length? And if not how to add extra digits to equalise those values?

Tags: python-3.x, list, compare, zero-padding

I'm doing a little coding in Python, and I came up to the issue that some of my values and not the same length.

Desired length is 15 characters

for example:

string = ['110000111100111', '100100110011011', '001101100110', '01011010001110', '111100111001', '1101100111011']

Some of these values are different, and I want to add zeros to equalise them to the same length. Specifically by adding some zeros to those values that are shorter.

Can someone give me a hand on this?

Many thanks!

I tried comparing them and finding shorter values in the list. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = ['110000111100111', '100100110011011', '001101100110', '01011010001110', '1100111001', '1101100111011']

s = [x.zfill(15) for x in s]
```

`zfill()` will pad a string with zeros on the left, up to the desired string length.

Comment: Thank you! I tried before with zFill but did the for loop and if statement. Thank you

Comment: No problem! You can click the green checkmark next to my answer to accept it, if it gave you what you needed.